# How to save and get next and previous data in linked list?

Tags: c, linux, list, linked-list

Good day. Anyone knows how to next and previous data using linkedlist in c? I'm getting NULL value after i get the previous data in linked list, sample if i move to right key (pass the index i wanted to get), there's nothing wrong in getting next data but if I move my key to left i got NULL value even if I pass an index again and get the data i needed. Here's my sample add and get linked list code.

```
typedef struct samp{
int idx;
char *name;
struct samp *next;
}sampLink;



sampLink *head=NULL,tail=NULL,test;
int addList(int idx,char *name){
  sampLink *tryi=NULL;
  tryi=(sampLink*)calloc(1,sizeof(sampLink));
  tryi->idx=idx;
  tryi->name=strdup(name);
  tryi->next=NULL;

  if(head==NULL){
    head=tryi;
    tail=tryi;
  }else{
    tail->next=tryi;
    tail=tail->next;
  }
  return 0;
}

sampLink *getList(int idx){
do{
    if(idx==head->idx){
      return head;
    }
    head=head->next;
  }while(head!=NULL);
  return head;
}
```

for moveRight

```
void moveRight(){
int i=0;
test=getList(i);
i++;
}
```

for left just minus sign. Hope someone will help me.Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by saving permanent data? If you want the data to be persistent, then you have to write it to disk.

Comment: @nhahtdh i mean i can get the next and previous whatever the position or index of it

Answer (score 1):

If you are really trying to achieve left/right movement, then just adding a minus won't do. You need to implement a doubly linked list in order to be able to move in both directions.

You might be getting NULL return when moving left because you are changing the head pointer when moving right and you lose some nodes once you change the head pointer as your search is not bidirectional since it's not a doubly linked list, hence returning the end node (NULL).

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear from your question as to what you are trying to achieve. But, still, you can find some pointers below:

1. It is always suggested to maintain a pointer to the 'head' of a linked list always. But, you keep modifying it in your moveRight function.
2. If you want to move left and right seamlessly, then it is best to implement a doubly linked-list.

With your current singly linked list solution, you can try the below code for getList

```
sampLink *getList(int idx)
{ 
  sampLink *temp = head;
  do{     
       if(idx==temp->idx)
       {       
         return temp;     
       }     
      temp=temp->next;   

    }while(temp!=NULL);   //Now, the function only keeps modifying the temp pointer rather than the head pointer, so each time you call the function, if idx is valid, it will return a pointer.

 return NULL; //If you had encountered a node which is having idx, you would have returned in the loop itself, so returning NULL here.
}
```